# How to read a yaml file through a dsl script - jenkins

Tags: github, jenkins, groovy, yaml, dsl

I've developed a seed job (which is a freestyle project) on Jenkins. This job takes specific parameters like 'name' and 'gitrepourl'. Now, my goal is to automate this process by using a YAML file that contains these parameters. I'd like my DSL script to read these parameters from the YAML file. Could you please guide me on where to create this file and how to integrate it with Jenkins?

For your reference, I'm currently testing this with the 'Process DSL Script' build step. However, I'm interested in accessing my script from a GitHub repository. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to achieve that either

I attempted to utilize the 'parameterized' option by including a file to serve as a YAML file. However, I'm still facing some confusion regarding this approach

Answer (score 0):

Why not switch to a `Pipeline` project?  Create a `Jenkinsfile` in your git repo at the root.  Then you can write your Jenkins pipeline in that script like so:

```
pipeline {
   agent any

   stages {
       stage("checkout") {
          steps {
             git url: "https://github.com/github/git.git", branch: "main", credentialsId: "some-user"
          }          
       }
       step("Process YAML") {
          script {
             def data = readYaml file: "some_config.yml"
             println( data.someField )
          }
       }
   }
}
```

Then you can check in your YAML file you want to read (ie `some_config.yml`) next to the `Jenkinsfile` and use `readYaml` to read the config file in the repo into your pipeline script.

For Job DSL it works similar but it's different APIs.  You still just add the YAML script to your repository and you can load it from the Job DSL:

```
job('example') {
  steps {
    shell('echo Hello World!')
    
  }
}
```

There isn't a direct statement to read yaml files from the API in Jobs DSL, but you can invoke Groovy scripts in order to use the YAML API in there.  Here is an example: [Jenkins DSL - Parse Yaml for complex processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47443106/jenkins-dsl-parse-yaml-for-complex-processing?rq=1)

Comment: but this is just a small part of a big  project so i really can 't change into a pipline job!

Comment: So Job-DSL is almost like a Pipeline project, but you can use it in a freestyle project. This isn't going to be as simple as the Pipeline, but I updated my answer.